# How can I uninstall an application in Windows using Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, uninstallation

Is it possible to uninstall an application in Windows using a Perl script?

Comment: Are you trying to uninstall any application or particular applications? Some come with uninstaller programs.

Comment: some windows based application like ymessenger or gtalk or small appplication. we generrally uninstall it from control panels--> Add / Remove programs but through perl how it is possible?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is any standard Perl module which accepts the application name and uninstalls it. To uninstall an application, you need to know its uninstaller application name/path. You can launch the uninstaller application from the Perl script by calling it in the *[system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)* function.

Comment: Also if unuinstaller does not support silent uninstalling, you'd have to click buttons it wants then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know every step you did in the installation process like inserting registry keys and which files and directories were generated in the installation proccess.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about Perl, but you might be able to use [Msiexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262(WS.10).aspx).